# Adding attribute to body tag with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, attributes

I'm trying to add the `bgcolor` attribute to the `body` tag with PHP. 
Using `getElement()` and `setAttribute()` won't work in PHP.
Does anyone know a solution?
I want to change the background color of the body with PHP, so any other solutions using PHP would be great too.

Edit:
For an assignment that's way outdated we HAVE to use PHP to change the backgroundcolor and we need to use bgcolor. With a POST form with some radiobuttons and a Submit button we need to change the bgcolor. Up to this I used echo to ADD a  tag after there is a  tag already. Any ideas on that?

Edit2:
I tried to echo the in the bgcolor attribute, but that seems to stop the full page from loading, so that doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Welcome to the future! You don't want to add the "bgcolor" attribute anymore. Nowadays we are using CSS

Comment: bgcolor is not deprecated ? I think you should use css style instead...

Comment: Why do you need PHP to do this. Just write it in HTML.

Comment: Are you sure it's a PHP thing?

Comment: I know bgcolor is outdated, and I wouldn't use PHP at all, but please check out my edit in my question.

Comment: But you did not explain why PHP. Do you have the background color as a variable? Anyway, you effectively don't change it, you just set it when you render your page. And it cannot be changed again, unless you refresh your page (and therefore you hit server-side PHP).

Comment: For an assigment we have to use PHP, to learn that. One excercise is changing the bgcolor with a POST form. I use PHP to check which radio buttons is checked and then assign the correct color to a $color variable.

Comment: Please post some code. I guess your people want you to do the assignment yourself if they want you to learn. ;) So try something and we'll help you find any errors in your code.

Comment: I understand that completely ;) I have a working script, but that uses echo to add a complete new <body bgcolor="..."> tag in the page. I might have phrased the question wrong, since I want to find a better solution. My question is answered but I thought maybe there was a nicer solution. Thanks for your time and solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server side! If you want to do it with php simple echo it like this

```
<?php echo '<body style="background-color:#000">'; ?>
```

otherwise you will need to do it in javascript with

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#000';
```

hope that help

Comment: Maybe he is obtaining the back color on the server-side. From a database, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I was using an echo with a <body bgcolor="..."> already, but that seems a bit untidy ;)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to inject this somewhere in your html:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: <?php echo $color; ?> !important;
    }
</style>
```

Then before this code is run, define `$color` to hold a color value like `#cccccc`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually you shoudn't use bgcolor anymore. Instead, give a css style to the body tag:

```
<?php
   $color = "#004422";
?>

<body style="background-color:<?php echo $color; ?>">

   <!-- CONTENT -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline styles (wheter in `<head>`, wheter in `<body>` with `scoped` attribute) or variables.

```
...
<style>
  body {
    background-color: <?php echo $body_bgcolor; ?>
  }
</style>
...
```

or

```
<body style="background-color: <?php echo $body_bgcolor; ?>">
...
</body>
```